# selected column discretize in weka

Tags: data-mining, weka, discretization

Is it possible to discretize selected column in weka ? I have 42 columns in my data set and I want to discretize (divide in intervals) only longitude and latitude but all columns are discretizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property in Discretize (attributeIndices) that allows you to specify the attributes to apply the filter to:

[image]

Just enter the attributes here and you should be good to go.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you please specify the input format? I want to descretize `age` and `income` columns, but when I added `age,income` into `attributeIndices` field, it throws error `invalid range list at age`